# Synaptics touchpad driver crashes

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, synaptics-touchpad

My touchpad crashes when my PC is under high use. The click functions still work but the movement of the pointer does work and other functions of the touch pad itself are not working either. The computer is not over-worked when this happens however, as the keyboard is still immediately responsive (the windows key, for example, brings up the start screen very responsively, ctrl-shft-esc to task manager is very quick too).

Is there something I can do to stop the touchpad crashing so much, when the computer clearly is still responsive in every other regard?

Details:
Clevo we550eu, Windows 8.1 Pro, intel i7-3632qm, driver version 16.3.15.1

Comment: The official [Clevo support site](http://www.clevo.com/en/e-services/download/ftpOut.asp?Lmodel=W54xEU&ltype=7&submit=+GO+) provides an updated driver (version `17.0.9.1` to be precise) designed for Windows 8.1. Download and install it, then restart Windows and see whether you still get the same issues.

Comment: I downloaded the driver, and uninstalled the prvious driver as recommended. The new driver says it has installed but has not; the driver does not appear in the mouse settings. What has happended?

Comment: it appears i can't update to the new version when i can reinstall the current driver.